# What OpenCv function will I use to detect disease in a leaf implemented on Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, java-native-interface

Currently I am working on a project that detects disease in a leaf (spot/discolored), rice leaf in specific.

It is android based which uses Opencv library. Now the problem is I am very new to Android programming as well as in OpenCv. I just completed the setup.

Could you help me what functions or features in OpenCv are possible to use in my project? And also, do I need to use native c++ or plain java?

Thank you, and I am looking forward for your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

segment the diseased part first. You can do that without using JNI part

Answer (score 2):

Use contour to segment the disease part. Use histogram to identify the damage part.

Comment: Thank you John I am currently doing what you have suggested.